# How does うんざり work in the Present Indicative, Causative, Passive, and Causative-passive tenses

Tags: grammar, verbs, passive-voice, causation

Consider the following:

> - そいつはひどく鼻持ちならないやつで、私をすっかり**うんざりさせる**。(That guy is so obnoxious that he really turns me off.)
> - あなたを**うんざりさせる**ものは何ですか？(What turns you off?)
> - 痛み以上に私を**うんざりさせる**ものはない。(Nothing turns me off more than pain.)
> - 自分の悩み事で人を**うんざりさせて**はいけないよ。(Don't bore people with your problems.)
> - 非常に**うんざりさせる**人　(thundering bore)
> - **うんざりさせられる**状況　(irksome situation)
> - **うんざりさせられる**試験　(boring exam)
> - あの子には**うんざりする**。(The kid is a pain in the neck)

This may be due to a lack of adequate understanding of Japanese grammar, but I'm a bit confused as to how a number of different formations are used with this word to mean the same thing.

> うんざりさせられる状況

a situation that makes me bored/turned off

> あの状況にはうんざりさせられる　　（is this correct?)

That situation turned me off/irked me.

Could I also say

あの状況にはうんざりする

or

あの状況にはうんざりさせる
?

I apologize if this question is too broad.

Comment: OK still new here so I didn't know that. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> あの状況にはうんざりする

Yes it sounds correct.

> あの状況にはうんざりさせる ?

No, because it literally sounds like YOU are feeding up something (it should be you who are fed up). "させる" is let someone do something, generally.

So you can say instead

あの状況にはうんざりさせられる

as you mentioned.

Comment: ありがとう。would this be incorrect?
あの状況は私をうんざりさせる。

Comment: No it's OK. It makes sense.